# Magento Customer Group Events

Tags: magento, events

I'm interested in Magento (backend) Customer Group Events (add/edit/save/etc)

I found out that for post save event, event is: **customer_group_save_after**, so probably for pre save it will be: customer_group_save_after

I am very interested in add(new) and edit actions events, since I need to alter the group form before displaying it.

If anyone knows, I'll send a bear through my wi/fi ;).

Comment: I think you should use event `customer_group_load_after`

Comment: @AleksandrIvashchenko Thank you, the event is correct, but I think it is triggered too soon. I need an event from which I could catch the Group_Edit block and alter its form. Any idea?

Comment: I have not found suitable event except for `adminhtml_block_html_before` but it's common event for system and you should be carefully when нщг will use it or you can add needed event to code and work with it

Comment: @AleksandrIvashchenko Thank you Aleksandr. In the end, I've chosen to use the same event as you told me (`adminhtml_block_html_before`) and search by block's type.